# Vertx Java - How do I use a compositefuture to update multiple documents using mongoclient

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

I'm trying to update multiple documents in my vertx microservice using the vertx mongodb client. I'm trying to use composite futures for the same. I wish to return a response when all the documents have been updated.

```html
private static void replaceQuestion(JsonObject query, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler) {
  Mongo.getInstance().getClient().replaceOne("questions", query, updateRes -> {
   if (updateRes.succeeded()) {
    handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(true));
   } else {
    handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(deleteRes.cause()));
   }
  });
 }
```

I want to get this method to return a Future object that I can add in a CompositeFuture.

Can anyone help out?!

Comment: Just change the return type of method to be `Future` and then `CompositeFuture.all(future1,future2).sethandler(r -> {})`

Comment: Setting the return type to `Future` won't work, as the Mongo query will return an object of type `MongoClient`. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to return an object of type `Future` instead of `MongoClient`

Comment: `public Future<JsonObject> replaceQuestion(){}` Futures can return type

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `Future` and use the `Future.completer` method:

```
private static Future<Boolean> replaceQuestion(JsonObject query) {
    Future<Boolean> future = Future.future();
    Mongo.getInstance().getClient().replaceOne("questions", query, future.completer());
    return future;
}
```

More details in the [Concurrent Composition](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_concurrent_composition) chapter of the Vert.x docs.